# ERROR in C# API project after upgrading .NET framework from 4.0 to 4.6.1 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#

I upgraded the C# API project from .NET 4.0 to 4.6.1 also upgraded NuGet. Now i am getting this error when i run the app. Any idea why? 
I am using visual studio 2017.

```
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in System.Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\d7da21eb\0001468a_5445d401\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\7d20d335\00d0a76d_64aece01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\c74e1aab\e1e3c6da_9bcfd401\BAH.IS_Finance.JE_API.Common.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\09c0d87d\54d37bdf_9bcfd401\BAH.IS_Finance.JE_API.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\8ece9ffb\00c9408f_a432d401\CommonServiceLocator.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\31b5d62f\0097c37f_224cd301\EntityFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\aaa31f4e\00c4f480_224cd301\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\281138df\00af8edd_d9bbd401\EPPlus.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\4f3e94a8\00532d11_cfb4d401\FluentValidation.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\52bbc4fd\00805e12_cfb4d401\FluentValidation.ValidatorAttribute.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\50216163\00805e12_cfb4d401\FluentValidation.WebApi.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\59e7ac8f\000b50c7_6b98d201\log4net.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Activities\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Activities.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\7dec418d\001f5ac0_66efd201\Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\fc4ba4d7\0051f857_b0bed401\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\ca8d17b9\0078b181_b0bed401\Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\2a17423c\00028bc0_9fbed401\Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\9709a83a\006cc1d2_b0bed401\Microsoft.AI.Web.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\5dda1770\004508a9_b0bed401\Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\a39386ee\00708ca1_9fbed401\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\e0c7cf69\00ffa231_6681d401\Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\9931726f\00252a1f_d77ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\a3a76c7a\007f8c21_d77ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\a3a4519c\00d0e791_d87ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\b987bb8b\002a4a94_d87ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\86729497\00d3764c_d77ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\9ae051e7\00a6454b_d77ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\021077e2\009e961b_d77ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\09a5215a\008b2415_65b4d401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\a9f9a63d\00252a1f_d77ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\a5c9bdef\0071651a_d77ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\39bd1602\0055170c_d77ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\879a2689\0081f0aa_d87ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\5691c750\00db52ad_d87ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\baadd14d\001626c9_65b4d401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\83cef19f\00db52ad_d87ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\e154e3fe\00db52ad_d87ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\74e10869\00337e57_d87ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\e9ebcca6\007cfd66_d87ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\bedf5964\005b3728_65b4d401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\6aa21c56\0060af58_d87ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\b1cc3ae4\009e961b_d77ad401\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\abaaaf0d\00c7520e_2b18cf01\Microsoft.BusinessData.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\6c313a15\006b076f_b1ecd301\Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\90ec5258\007b7e1e_7f79d401\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

Comment: Check the pool framework in iis

Comment: If you uncheck "Just My Code" in debugging settings, you should be able to debug such exceptions and learn what might be the cause.

Comment: Do you have the same behavior with a fresh new project using .Net 4.6.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These aren't errors, per se. They're informational messages saying that debug symbols could/couldn't be found for the each of the assemblies in question.

> 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

That's an assembly that forms part of the .NET Framework, for which PDB files aren't supplied, vs:

> 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131958557689752173): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\42793b1e\10d72f95\assembly\dl3\09c0d87d\54d37bdf_9bcfd401\BAH.IS_Finance.JE_API.dll'. Symbols loaded.

That's (presumably!) one of the assemblies that forms part of your application. Note that at the end it states *Symbols loaded*, which indicates that a PDB file has been found and loaded, because Visual Studio generated them and thus they're available.